# "Колыхающийся" - возможно ли?

Tags: причастия

Можно ли говорить "колыхающийся"?

Answer (score 4):

**Колышется или колыхается?**

"Колышется" ― более употребительная (нейтральная) форма, "колыхается" встречается реже (обычно в разговорной или поэтической речи), например: "Тень несозданных созданий **колыхается** во сне ...(В. Брюсов).

Образованные от этих глагольных форм **причастия ведут себя примерно так же:**

Через несколько секунд бассейн был полон, и кот, трижды перевернувшись в воздухе, обрушился в **колыхающийся** коньяк. [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 2 (1929-1940)]

Но в эту минуту, когда я находился лицом к треножнику, всматриваясь в **колыхающийся** туман... [В. Я. Брюсов. Огненный ангел (1908)]

И тут, маленький, **колышащийся** от горя, слабости, пьянства, поднялся Иван Иваныч и заговорил, расплескивая водку дрожащей крапчатой ручонкой: (Ю. М. Нагибин).

Answer (score 1):

Словарь допускает, причем как вполне равноправный вариант.

Но вообще-то выглядит то ли слегка просторечным, то ли сильно устаревшим.